# Calculate tide table

Tags: weather

I develop software that shows the tide table for a given area and day.

I need to know the "formula" to calculate the tide table of an area for a given day.

My intention is to develop the application in PHP, but I really do not care programming language, because once you know how to calculate the tide table, and what can I implement in any language.

Thanks for the help.
Greetings!.

Comment: I searched for days but have not found anything concrete. What I seek is the formula (and the meaning of its parameters) to find out the tide table. I guess based on the current day you can calculate your tide table.

Comment: well then this is not the right place to look for a oceanographic formula, don't you think?

Comment: I think you would probably be better off getting the tide tables from the internet for the area you are interested in, if they are available (a lot are and you can often get them with an HTTP GET request and parse the result), rather than trying to calculate them yourself.  Here is some information about tides regardless if you do want to attempt to calculate them it is a starting point:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide - I think it is not so trivial.

Comment: @MichalPlško Maybe, but do not lose anything by asking. I hope nothing to be offended by this question.

Comment: @lobo - well, you may always try, but your question is probably going to be deleted as being off topic...

Comment: @lobo - maybe you would be better of with what kmp said or at one of the other portals like http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichalPlško Maybe I should ask math.stackexchange.com or physics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @lobo - well, not sure if it's really a mathematical theory problem....

Comment: @kmp It was the first thing I sought. I wanted a service that offers information tide table (via HTTP GET or similar) for Spain, but nothing found. I have several days searching to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Took me like 5min of searching:

- http://tides.mobilegeographics.com/locations/854.html
- [tidal information (@the end of the table)](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html)
- http://ocean.peterbrueggeman.com/tidepredict.html
- http://www.weathercharts.org/

Maybe it helps you out.

NOTE: You don't have to get an API. You can just steal any data from a HTML source with [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). I am doing this with some EU databases too... Maybe not too legal, but who cares...